# In tcpdump filtering is "port" redundant with "tcp"?

Tags: tcpdump, filtering

Why would one want to force "tcp" in a "tcpdump" filter when using "port", given port numbers are defined in TCP Headers (as opposed to IP)
In other words, is

```
tcpdump tcp and port 10000
```

synonym to

```
tcpdump port 10000
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

- `tcp and port 10000` means "tcp port 10000"
- `port 10000` means "tcp port 10000 or udp port 10000" and is a synonym for `(tcp or udp) and port 10000`

I would force TCP if I wanted, for example, to see only DNS packets that are being transported over TCP (as opposed to the default UDP).

---

(`tcpdump` should have been named `packetdump` or `netdump` since it can dump packet information as low as layer 2, rather than layer 4 which its name implies.)